# Finding the range of smallest elements

Tags: c++, sorting, data-structures

Basically a follow-up question to my old question here: [Choosing specific objects satisfying conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669733/choosing-specific-objects-satisfying-conditions)

I have objects called variables that can either be assigned or unassigned. Every variable has a domain, which means the values a variable can be assigned to. For example a variable might take on values from 1 to 32. I can query the size of a variable in constant time with a very highly-optimized method.

One important operation is to somehow find the range of unassigned elements with the smallest domain sizes. For this I have a vector of pointers to all variable-objects. Bookkeeping is done in order to maintain an invariant which says that pointers to all unassigned variables occur first before all assigned ones.

As time steps go by, the variables change in a dynamic way that their domain sizes change and unassigned variables might become assigned and vice versa. When the states of the variables change, they are swapped so that invariant once again holds. This means that the size of the vector stays the same throughout the execution of the program.

Then comes my question: finding efficiently the range of unassigned variables that have the smallest domain size. What I am doing now: maintain the invariant with the vector of pointers. Then, when I need to find the range of elements, I fully sort the part of the vector containing pointers to the unassigned variables.

This is incredibly slow. According to the Visual Studio profiler I am using around 50% of total time sorting. These ranges of pointer elements I am sorting are quite small, at most 500-600 hundred elements. Is there a possible reason for this?

Actually before this scheme, I was using a method that did not rely on sorting. It *felt* it should be slower and even asymptotically it was. I am seeing very big negative impacts in performance with my new scheme, and sorting is the one doing the biggest amount of work.

Is there anything I could try? Sorting 500-600 elements should be nothing on modern hardware, right (and with std::sort)? std::partial_sort doesn't really change the situation either.

I am a bit unsure if I could provide you with any more useful info, but please let me know if there is something. I am really stunned by this phenomenon, whatever is causing it. I am using C++ if that matters, but this could be seen as language-independent question as well I suppose.

**EDIT:** Here's a simplified example:

A zero in this vector designates assigned variables, non-zero elements mean unassigned variables with that domain size. Let's say my vector looks like this:

```
{1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

Then my algorithm takes one step and changes the states of the variables. The vector then looks like

```
{2, 0, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}
```

Right now the invariant is violated: there are unassigned variables in the front. I need to do something to correct this. Then I need to find the range of elements with the smallest values. Fixing and sorting produces for example then:

```
{1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

**EDIT2:**

Additional details about the problem. There are not many potential different value ranges for the unassigned variables. I do know it in advance and the maximum value is always at most 32, with 1 always being the lowest value. The changes to the values might occur anywhere in the set of elements, but when it happens, on one step each changing value changes by at most 1. And yes, I need to find all the elements with the lowest value.

Yes, I believe the reordering can be performed when the bookkeeping is performed. We can assume that we are starting with a sorted range and the invariant holds. But then comes the question, how does one actually go about doing the reordering? OK, probably I should check which elements have changed, and somehow let them float into their right places. Any ideas how to do this (on code level)? Is the data structure itself a good idea in the first place?

The first EDIT was a bit misleading, it is now corrected. So the ranges are always at most 500-600 elements, with many concecutive values in a small range (at most 1 to 32).

**EDIT3:**

If anyone is curious, I'll explain the previous approach that was much faster and did not rely on sorting. I believe all this can be done even more efficiently, so that's why I wanted to try changing to another scheme.

The idea was as follows: at every point, I would have a vector of pointers that contains *only* the elements with the smallest domain value. Then the algorithm does its work and something happens to the variables. First, I do a linear scan through all variables and check to see if the smallest domain value has changed. If it has, I rebuild the vector of elements. If it has not, I check the small range of pointers and either add or remove elements to make the invariant hold again (the container holds all the unassigned variables with the smallest domain).

I have a gut feeling this could be faster with my new scheme, since the size of the vector stays constant, elements are only swapped or rotated in it. I might be totally wrong though, it's very hard to say what really is efficient for the hardware.

Comment: Define "nothing"; it depends how many times you're doing it!  Also, can you define what you mean by "range" in this context?

Comment: @Oli Range means a subset of the vector of pointers. And yes, very true, I'll see if I can come up with something else than always sorting the whole range. I am doing it very often and apparently it is costly even if the vector is "almost sorted" already.

Comment: Are there many potential different value ranges for the unassigned variables? How do they change? Can you perform the reordering while you are performing the bookkeeping that will move assigned variables to the end? Do you need to find one/all elements with the smallest range? Or do you need to find the N smallest ranges? or... There are many things that you haven't told about the problem...

Comment: @David Ofcourse, good points! I have a feeling I could answer this immediately, but I'll analyze it a bit more carefully and let you know soon.

Comment: @David Additional details updated, a faster way of doing probably is found with these details...

Comment: Is the order of elements in the vector important for the iterations?

Comment: @David No, it is not important.

Answer (score 0):

If I understanded it corretly you only want to sort about 500-600 pointers to object, but its too slow for you. First what algorithm do you use? some algorithm has almost linear complexity in mostly sorted data. if your data only contains a few unsorted elements, you might want to try insertion sort (it takes O(n^2) on avarage, it works well on mostly sorted data), or TimSort (its a little hard to implement but its really quick).

i don't know if the 1..32 range is just an exaple, but if you really work with such a small set of values, the fastest way of sorting is when you create 32 list (linked list for example), and when you encounter the value X, you put it in the X-th list. when your done, you select the first not empty list, and there you have it.

Comment: Correct. I am using the standard C++ std::sort, which is actually Introsort. The range 1..32 is very real and happens in practice, therefore your idea would be feasible. I'm afraid to guess its impact on performance, but I will try it out :)

Comment: I tried out your scheme and it did not make much of an difference. I believe one can can conclude from this that sorting itself is the problem. Everything else happens quickly, but I often need to do this operation and I cannot afford to sort the 500-600 elements on every round of my algorithm. Something more clever is needed.

Comment: I suggested in a comment a solution that would not involve sorting, but rather using separate lists for each range and then moving elements from one list to another when the values are updated. Each update (removal from one list and insertion in another) is a constant time operation, so it should not have a great impact. Even if you don't do it with the update, but in a later step, it will be linear on the number of elements, which is much better than any alternative that involves sorting.